# Почему не обновляется ListView?

Tags: android

реализовал код из этого примера:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30711517/how-to-change-the-contents-of-listview-on-item-click/30711959#30711959

предполагается, что по клику на список, строка в нем заменяется на заданную

при клике на строку `listView` элемент в `ItemAdapter` обновился, а `listView` остался таким же

как заставить обновляться `ListView` после обновления `ItemAdapter` ?

**добавил**

Activity class:

```
public class ItemActivity extends Activity {

    private ListView listView;
    private ItemAdapter itemListAdapter;
    private List<Item> itemList = new ArrayList<Item>();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.list);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        itemListAdapter = new ItemAdapter(itemList, this);
        listView.setAdapter(itemListAdapter);
        listView.setFastScrollEnabled(true);

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // add some items
        itemList.add(new Item("Charlie"));
        itemList.add(new Item("Jenny"));

        //add new items and changes to adapter
        itemListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
            @Override

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){

                String beforeName = itemListAdapter.getItem(position).getItemName().toString();

                String changedName = "Thomas";
                itemListAdapter.getItem(position).setItemName(changedName);

            }

        });
    }
}
```

так заработало:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){

    String beforeName = itemListAdapter.getItem(position).getItemName().toString();

    String changedName = "Thomas";
    itemListAdapter.getItem(position).setItemName(changedName);
    itemListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

а так не хочет:

```
itemListAdapter = new ItemAdapter(itemList, this);
itemListAdapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);
listView.setAdapter(itemListAdapter);
```

Comment: покажите код. adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() должен обновлять ваш лист

Comment: @АндроидАндроид, дополнил вопрос